# What is this small spruce-like plant

Tags: trees

[image: Top view]

[image: Side view]

Does anyone know what kind of tree this is? Should we keep it indoors, or is it better off outdoors. We're in the Ottawa, Canada area.

Thanks.

Comment: Check how many trees are in that pot - if  more than one get advice whether to separate or thin them if you want the classic growth form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That look like a Norfolk Island Pine (*Araucaria heterophylla*). It's a tropical tree, so definitely keep it indoors, although you could of course keep it outside in the summer. [Here](https://www.thoughtco.com/growing-norfolk-island-pine-1343363) are some basic care instructions.